# How to use groupby max in own groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following df

```
d = {'CAT':['C1','C2','C1','C2'],'A': [10, 20,30,40], 'B': [3, 4,10,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I am trying to include a new column obtained by dividing 'A' by the highest 'B' it is category ('CAT'). That is, I want to divide 10 by 10, 20 by 4, 10 by 10 and 40 by 4 to obtain the following df

```
d = {'CAT':['C1','C2','C1','C2'],'A': [10, 20,30,40], 'B': [3, 4,10,3], 'C':[1,5,3,10]}
```

Any suggestions?

---

---

I find it easy to do without having to condition/groupby on CAT

```
d = {'A': [10, 20,30,40], 'B': [3, 4,10,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x:x.A/max(df1['B']),axis=1)
```

but with 'CAT' I am having a hard time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in one line; I only broke it into separate lines for more clarity. [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) allows replication of the groupby accross the entire dataframe; with that we can get the results for column C :

```
grouping = df1.groupby("CAT").B.transform("max")
df1['C'] = df1.A.div(grouping)
df1



    CAT A   B   C
0   C1  10  3   1.0
1   C2  20  4   5.0
2   C1  30  10  3.0
3   C2  40  3   10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you're pretty much most of the way there with using apply. Depending on how big your actual dataset it, using apply *could* work out as inefficient, but ignoring that, you can solve your problem by the 'max' function on a filter of the dataframe rather than the df itself.

Or, just to get to the code:

```
df1['calculation'] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['A'] / max(df1[df1['CAT'] == row['CAT']]['B']), axis=1)
```